# How to retrieve a MAC Id using a system name in Python

Tags: python, network-programming, automated-tests

I have been asked to improve an automated test system that connects to a single device at a time in a given function area. Inside each given area there is a minimum of 10 devices (each one is connected to a single computer). What would be the best way to retrieve the MAC ID of the NIC on one of the computers using only the system name in Python to perform a verification check to determine whether or not the connection is to the right system to test?

Comment: do you mean get the mac address? I *think* you can only get the mac address of the computer, but i might be wrong. Have you looked at [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html)?

Comment: using the system name, you can get most of the relevant information pertaining to that system (i.e. OS Ver, IP Address, and DNS Infor)

Answer (score 0):

If as **will** suggests, you're looking for the MAC address, here's how you could grab it:

```py
import re
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
def get_MACs():
    c = re.compile(r'Physical Address[\. ]+?: ([\dA-F\-]+?)[\r\n]')
    return c.findall(Popen('ipconfig /all', stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0])
```

If that isn't what you were looking for, you could still do something similar to grab whatever you needed from the output.